# Method EF Core: Method 'Process' does not have implementationnot found

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I'm facing an error while trying to obtain information of the DbSets in a DbContext object by using Entity Framework core.I'm trying to instante the context by calling a method which receives a generic type T which might be childs of DbContext this way:

My DbContext object looks this way:

```
public class CatalogueContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ConnectorCatalogueItemConv> CatalogueItemConvs { get; set; }

    public CatalogueContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogueContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public CatalogueContext()
    {

    }
}

public T GetContext<T>() where T: DbContext, new()
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(ExternalTablesKey);
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), optionsBuilder.Options) as T;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share package imports from .csproj?

Comment: i just added it. you can check it out.

Comment: You need to understand what this method does before you try to fix it - or decide whether you even want it. There's no "bulk delete" or "bulk update" in the sense this package means. What the package does is insert the data into a staging table using SqlBulkCopy , join with the target on the primary keys and INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE as needed. This works for a small amount of data but if you frequently need to load lots of data you'd have to design the staging tables yourself, use proper indexes and quite possibly use more advanced techniques like partition switching

Comment: When you have lots of data an ORM like EF Core only adds overhead, no matter how you save the data. If you have 100K rows to insert, the last thing you want is to load all of them in memory and track them. That's simply not what ORMs are for

Answer (score 0):

Your `sqlServerOptions.AddTempTableSupport()` appears to be a custom extension method created by your organization. This method calls a method in a  Thinktecture assembly, but your application can't find that metho at runtime.

As always with a MissingMethodException this means you're running your application against another assembly than parts of it were compiled against.

Make sure that you use the same version everywhere.

Comment: If you google for it, it seems to be an unfortunately named method for creating staging tables for SqlBulkCopy to populate for bulk update/delete operations. Trying to "hide" complexity ends up making it harder to understand what's going on or what's wrong

Comment: I don't use Google, but "AddTempTableSupport" gives 4 (four) hits on DuckDuckGo so it doesn't appear to be a widespread method.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors usually are sign of some nuget version mismatch. Since you have not provided a full .csproj file it is hard to say which ones exactly, but there are several in question, like `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` is definitely should be upgraded to 6.x. I would assume that you have some package `Thinktecture.Something...` installed also so you need to update those to version which support 6.x version of EF Core (if it is one from [pawelgerr](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/pawelgerr) then latest 4.2.3 versions seems to be appropriate).